# ExtJS 4 code assist in Aptana 3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, aptana, aptana3

I started using ExtJS 4 framework for generating chart report in a web app development project. 
I am looking for up-to-date code assist for ExtJS 4 to release me from too much typing. I tried for long to find one, but it looks like all of them are out-of-date.

If anyone currently using ExtJS 4 code assist in Aptana (or some other IDE). Please give me a hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great! Finally find this [thread](http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/342-aptana-support-for-extjs-40) which answers my question. 
Download [extjs4.1.beta-v0.1.sdocml](http://www.thekuroko.com/aptana-sdocml-code-hinting-support/) can add code hinting into your ExtJS 4 Aptana project.

There is a lot instructions for adding Spket plugin to Eclipse/Aptana for ExtJS support. But it just never works for me...Not sure if anyone used it and get it worked out.

**UPDATE**: I am using [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) for ExtJS 4 development now, it has very good ExtJS support. Actually all the js files included in the project can be identified in WebStorm and thus code hinting is listed.

Comment: After years of searching, I finally found this in 2013!!